# Accessing unions in C using IA32 or x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, unions

If I have a union declared as so:

```
union u1 {
    struct s1 *h;
    struct s2 *i;
    char j;
};
```

How do I access either the first, second or third element with something like IA32 or any assembly?
If I'm understanding unions correct, the byte ordering of this union should take up only 4 bytes (IA32) since pointers in IA32 are 4 bytes.

Comment: Since the first two are just pointers and assembly doesn't care about types pointed to, you just load 4 bytes. `j` is a single byte, so you load 1 byte.

Comment: how the union is built is implementation defined.  you should never use unions across compile domains which certainly includes across different languages.   assembly doesnt generally have a notion of structs, unions, etc.  if you feel the need the simply reverse engineer what the specific compiler has produced and work with that, it will show you what offset in the union everything starts at and how large it is and then you can hardcode based on that.

Comment: @old_timer In practice, the way unions are laid out is pretty predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the members of the union share the initial address, so whatever member of a union you want to read, it's at the same position in memory, the only thing you need to change is how to interpret it.

If you have the address of an instance of `u1` in, say, `eax`, you can get the value of `h` or `i` (i.e. the address to which `h` or `i` point to) in, say, `ebx`, through a trivial

```
mov ebx, dword ptr[eax]
```

(both are the same, given that in assembly there's no real distinction between different pointer types)

as for reading `j` in `bl`, that would be

```
mov bl, byte ptr[eax]
```

---

*Edit*: as *Peter Cordes* rightly remarks, if you actually want to do full-register arithmetic with that, which is what would happen when using it in a mathematical expression in C, you need to sign-extend it if your `char` is signed, as generally is:

```
movsx ebx, byte ptr[ebx]
```

or zero-extend it if it's `unsigned`:

```
mobzx ebx, byte ptr[ebx]
```

---

For x86_64, that's essentially the same, changing some register/memory operands sizes:

```
mov rbx, qword ptr[rax]
```

or

```
mov bl, byte ptr[rax]
```

Comment: So for accessing the only distinction, I can make is with the suffix of the mov instruction?
Say if h and i were not stored in registers, how would it know which pointer to access?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. I don't get what you are asking; `h` and `i` here are not stored in registers, what is in a register here is the *address* of the `u1` instance; if it's not in a register (say, it's somewhere in memory), get it in a register through a `mov`.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm asking if I need to access say h, and I do `movl (%eax), %eax1`, how does the assembly code know that I want h and not i since they're both pointers and stored at the same address?

Comment: @George: ad assembly level it's a distinction that doesn't make sense. `h` and `i` share the value, differing in C only by "type of pointer", and "types of pointers" isn't a thing that exists in assembly, where you only have addresses and "how you use them". The `mov` will load the address of `h` or `i` into `ebx`, then if you are going to use it as an `s1` or as an `s2` will depend on how the rest of your code will use it.

Comment: For a more concrete example, imagine that instead of being `struct s1 *h` and `struct s2 *i` they were `int *h` and `char *i`. To load the address of both `h` and `i` you'd do the same `mov ebx, dword ptr[eax]`, but then if you were to read the actual pointed value, you'd have to do `mov ecx, dword ptr[ebx]` if you were reading `h`, and `mov cl, byte ptr[ebx]` if you were reading `i`.

Comment: Normally you want to `movzx ebx, byte ptr [eax]`, not merge with the old value of EBX/RBX.  (Or `movsx` if you actually want to use the 32-bit value, since this `char` = `signed char` in x86 ABIs.)